# PyPDF PdfReader IndirectObject

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to merge two pdf with forms into one pdf document.
Therefore, I'm using the following code:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader
from pypdf import PdfWriter

reader1 = PdfReader("tmp/output_Antrag.pdf")
reader1.add_form_topname("form1")

reader2 = PdfReader("tmp/output_Attachment.pdf")
reader2.add_form_topname("form2")

merger = PdfWriter()

merger.append(reader1)
merger.append(reader2)

output = open("document-output.pdf", "wb")
merger.write(output)
merger.close()
output.close()
```

Now I'm getting the following errors:

```
{'/T': 'form1',
 '/Kids': [IndirectObject(8, 0, 2257682635632),
  IndirectObject(9, 0, 2257682635632),
...
  IndirectObject(42, 0, 2257682635632)]}
```

As well as:

```
{'/T': 'form2',
 '/Kids': [IndirectObject(7, 0, 2257682636928),
  IndirectObject(8, 0, 2257682636928),
...
  IndirectObject(96, 0, 2257682636928)]}
```

Although this is not optimal, the main problem is that I'm losing all information (all data) from the filled-in forms. In other words: all fields in the merged document are empty.

Can somebody help and tell me how I can solve this problem?